# dkim missing with smtp postfix server for multiple domains?

Tags: email, smtp, certificate, postfix-mta, dkim

I have many domain on one server.

I want enable DKIM verification for each one. For do it, I follow [this tutorial](https://translate.google.fr/translate?sl=fr&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=fr&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.serveur-linux.info%2F2013%2F04%2Fdkim-postfix-plusieurs-domaines%2F&edit-text=)
Like said a the end of tutorial, I test my dkim DNS on http://dkimcore.org/c/keycheck

> This is a valid DKIM key record

So it's supose to works right now, but when I send an email, there is no DKIM signature and only "domainkeys=neutral (no sig); dkim=neutral (no sig)". (tested on yahoo and gmail.)

So what's wrong with this method?

EDIT:

mail.log when I send a mail (with PHP) said:

> opendkim[40952]: 628EF242A06: localhost [127.0.0.1] not internal
>   opendkim[40952]: 628EF242A06: not authenticated
>   opendkim[40952]: 628EF242A06: no signature data

other thing:

```
sudo opendkim-testkey -d mydomain.com -s default -k /etc/opendkim/keys/mydomain.com/default.private -v
```

response:

> opendkim-testkey: key not secure

So it's the method to generate keys which is bad?

Answer (score 1):

I add 127.0.0.1 and localhost to trusted host and used :

```
 sudo service postfix reload
```

Now it's working... enjoy ;)